# How Would You Plot CIs with an ANCOVA model

Tags: r

I'm working with a data set that involves a response variable (mass), a covariate (length), and a categorical independent variable (location) of a certain bird species. This data set looks like this:

[image: DATA FRAME]

In this case there are three locations (Orlando, Tampa, and another Floridian City) with ten observations each). I decided to run an ANCOVA using the lm function.

```
m1<- lm(mass.d ~ length.d + location)
```

I was able to plot this model with ggplot:

```
predm1<- predict(m1)
ggplot(YOUR_DATA, aes(length.d, mass.d, color = pop)) + geom_point() + 
geom_line(aes(y= predm1))
```

[image: ANCOVA model]

Now I would like to add my 95 percent confidence intervals.

[image: CIs]

I have the confidence intervals but I have very little idea on how to input them into my ggplot graph because I essentially have three different slopes for 3 different locations. I've been playing around with geom_ribbon but have not been able to find an answer.

Comment: You seem confused. On a graph you would plot the confidence band of predictions not the CIs of parameters. Look at help("predict.lm"). Or even help("geom_smooth").

Comment: I think I have my terminology mixed up as I'm pretty sure confidence bands can still be done with geom_ribbon right? @Roland

Comment: `predict` has an 'interval' parameter. Read the help page (again?). And do pay attention to the comments made for your questions in a more timely manner than you appear to be doing so far. You should also forget about pasting screenshots and instead learn to post text versions of data and results.

Comment: You could just use `visreg` like so, `visreg(m1, "length.d", by="location", overlay=TRUE)`

Comment: Please include your data etc as text rather than as images. Much more useful

Comment: @Remko Thank you sir! You're comment helped a lot!

Comment: "I'm pretty sure confidence bands can still be done with geom_ribbon right" No, they can't because there width is not constant if your model includes a slope.